# python with Ajax using django

Tags: javascript, python, django

**This is my function but when I run this on the django server I get an error**

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

    var url = '/update_item/'

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action': action})
    })

    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
    })

}
```

**The error say**

> cart.js:24 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/ 500 (Internal
> Server Error) uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
> JSON at position 0

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: share the backend code for this endpoint `/update_item/` , also a longer snippet of the JS code, since there is no syntax error in the code provided.

Comment: Is the problem solved? Do update the relevant code from views.py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```
// csrf token from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax
    
        function getToken(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        const csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');
```